# What is the best way for me to create a unique query string for the purposes of what I'm doing? (Generating video file)

Tags: javascript, url, query-string, client-side

For my site, the user uploads 2 files, the site redirects, and I generate a video file that the user can play. What should the URL for the site that's being redirected to look like, and what method would you recommend I use to generate a unique URL?

This has something to do with encoding and decoding I believe, but I'm not sure what as I haven't really delved into this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure i fully understand this question, but here goes an anwser.

It can look like however you want - could be  `www.foo.com/videos/?v=12345`, or `www.foo.com/videos/12345`, etc..you decide/config.

As for how to create this, i suggest an npm package like
https://www.npmjs.com/package/short-unique-id
https://www.npmjs.com/package/unique-string

as long as it's url-safe.
If you're waiting til database insertion is done in the backend, just get the unique id (which i'm assuming you're doing) you generated in the back end, then redirect.

Comment: Just like how YouTube creates unique query strings for all their videos, I want to do for mine.

Comment: @RPump The general idea is this - `1. user uploads file to server`, `2. server saves file on disk/cloud, and stores information about that file in a database`.  `3. that database entry has a unique ID - ie, MySQL's autoincrement number, or a custom generated one`